# Cannot verify rsa signature on Android

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I'm trying to sign an encrypted message with a private key and verify it in Java. This is my first time working with encryption and signatures so I'm not sure how it is supposed to work and I'm kind of stuck here. The verification always returns false.

Here I sign the message:

```
public byte[] rsaSign (byte[] data) {

byte[] cipherData = null;

try {

    RSAPrivateKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(signModulus, signExponent);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privKey = fact.generatePrivate(keySpec);

    Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    s.initSign(privKey);

    s.update(data);

    return s.sign();
}

return cipherData;
}
```

And here I try to verify the signature:

```
public boolean rsaVerify (byte[] data, byte[] signature) {

boolean success = false;

try {

    RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(signModulus, signPublicExponent);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);

    Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    s.initVerify(pubKey);

    s.update(data);

    success = s.verify(signature);

    return success;

} 

return false;
}
```

Can anyone see a problem? The keys are generated in C# and converted to BigIntegers in java.

Comment: For me this clearly look like a library related question and would be a lot better off at SO, as mentioned by Ilmari. You should strongly consider migrating your question as it's very likely to get answered on SO.

Comment: I did post it on SO but I haven't got any answer. I will consider making it self-contained and trying again. Thanks!

Comment: @user3685322: make sure to post the input values to whatever builds signModulus, signExponent, signPublicExponent; the problem might be there.

Answer (score 2):

Signature verification is failed because you are using a different `public key` in the verification method.
Use the `public key` to verify the signature which is consistent with the `private key` that is used into `rsaSign()` method.

Hope this will help you. Note that, this `public key` is consistent with the `private key` which is used in Signature Generation method :

```
/**
     * This method will sign message with RSA 2048 key
     * @return Void
     */
    public void rsaSign (String message) throws Exception {
        //key generation
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
        keyGen.initialize(2048, random);

        KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey priv = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey pub   = keyPair.getPublic();

        System.out.println("RSAPub key Mod for Sign/Verify  : " + Helper.toHex(((RSAPublicKey)pub).getModulus().toByteArray()));
        System.out.println("RSAPub key Exp for Sign/Verify  : " + Helper.toHex(((RSAPublicKey)pub).getPublicExponent().toByteArray()));

        //sign
        Signature dsa   = Signature.getInstance(signALG);
        dsa.initSign(priv);

        dsa.update(Helper.toByte(message));
        byte[] realSig = dsa.sign();
        System.out.println("RSA Sign-Data   : " + Helper.toHex(realSig));
    }


/**
     * This method verify signature with RSA public key
     * @param message The plain message
     * @param rsaMOD RSA Public key Modulus in string
     * @param rsaEXP RSA Public key Exponent in string
     * @param rsaSignData Signature which will be verified
     * @return true if verifications success, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean rsaVerify(String message, String rsaMOD, String rsaEXP, String rsaSignData) throws Exception {
        BigInteger modBigInteger = new BigInteger(Helper.toByte(rsaMOD));
        BigInteger exBigInteger = new BigInteger(Helper.toByte(rsaEXP));

        RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modBigInteger, exBigInteger);
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic(spec);

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(signALG);
        signature.initVerify(publicKey);
        signature.update(Helper.toByte(message));

        return signature.verify(Helper.toByte(rsaSignData));
    }
```

Comment: No. RSAPublicKeySpec has parameters, and the question states that they have been generated in C#.

Comment: I think OP broke the consistency of the Key-pair. @fgrieu

Comment: I'm OK with the new intro; I had issue with [version 1 of the answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/25799/1) because I see no sign that the code in the question is " _generating a new public key in the verification method_ "

Comment: What do you mean broke the consistency of the key-pair? I generated the key-pair in c# and transferred them to my android app mainly for testing. The public key will be used server-side eventually.

Comment: Breaking the consistency means, you use a private key for signature generation, but don't use the corresponding public key to verify that signature. Do you try the code I posted in the answer?

Comment: FYI:
calling GetEncoded() on the private key returns null in Android 4.1. 

https://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/xamarin/0001.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try and test these things locally first, with your own generated key pair. If that fails your code is wrong - it's a very simple wrapper around Java `Signature` so that's not at all that likely.

You already used a complete specification of the signature algorithm, so provider defaults are not an issue here.

Then check the correctness of the data on both sides by printing it out in Hex or Base64 right before signature generation/verification. If that fails you've got an I/O or encoding/decoding error. Encoding/decoding errors & string handling make up about 30% of the total of cryptography related questions!

Finally you could obtain and compare the modulus of the private and public key. If the moduli don't match then you're using a private and public key of a different key pair, and signature verification will of course always fail.